# Why unable to install Writer2LaTeX - 1.4 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, java, latex, libreoffice-writer

I want to add Writer2LaTeX - 1.4 extension to Libreoffice 5. Details are as follow:

platorm: Ubuntu16.04 LTS(32bit), english

LibreOffice Writer Version: 5.1.6.2

I got Writer2Latexfrom from [here](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/writer2latex-1).

Then tried to install Writer2Latex using Extension Manager

I got the following error when I tried to add Writer2Latex in LibreOffice Writer:
"java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

[image]

How can I fix this problem?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try in command line

```
sudo apt-get insall libreoffice-writer2latex
```

if not working install java if not already installed

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

After these steps, it was possible for me to export the document as LaTex file